# PHP rows to variables

Tags: php, for-loop

I wanna do a dynamic gallery takin the images names and locations (folders where they are in) from a database.
Gallery would have always 15 photos (the last entrys in the db) so I need to sabe the images directory and names into variables to pass they to the HTML for the carousel.

I got a column "álbum_name" with the name of the álbum (folder where the image is in) and another called "img_name" wich gots the imagenames.jpg, so I need to add a / between they. I was thinking in something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT album_name, img_name FROM gallery WHERE status = 1 ORDER by date DESC LIMIT 15";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$photo0;
$photo1;
$photo2;
$photo3;
$photo4;
$photo5;
$photo6;
$photo7;
$photo8;
$photo9;
$photo10;
$photo11;
$photo12;
$photo13;
$photo14;

$img_num = mysqli_num_rows($result );

for ($i = 0; $i < $img_num ; $i++) {
// and here something to pass for each row álbum_name . "/" . img_name to the variables.
}
```

I was looking that for this things PHP man use while and fech_array or fech_row, but they doesnt do what I m tryng to...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look to the [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

It is very easy to get an array of results, see this example (code not tested, but it should work):

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");  // Create a connection

$mysqli->query("SELECT album_name, img_name FROM gallery WHERE status = 1 ORDER by date DESC LIMIT 15");      // Perform the query

$gallery = $mysqli->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); // Get the results. MYSQLI_ASSOC is used here to return an associative array with the name of each table field
```

That's it! You can see what's inside your array $gallery

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($gallery);
echo '</pre'>;
```

And you can iterate it without using any counter with a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)! :D

```
<?php
foreach ($gallery as $image) {
    echo '<p>Album name:'.$image['album_name'].'</p>';
    echo '<img src="/images/'.img_name.'/>"';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Doesn't work for exactly as is for this case, but it gives me lot of ideas... one more question, I tryed this: `$num_resultados = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
echo $num_resultados;
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($row as $image) {
    echo $image;
}`
and I got 15 from result of row numbers, but the echo $image only returns me one line, don't you know why? Thanks again.

Comment: Why this doesn't work for your case?

Try to paste here the output of this:
`echo '<p>'.$row[0].'</p>';
    echo '<p>'.$row[1].'</p>';
    echo '<p>'.$row[2].'</p>';`

(Also a paste from the original output of your foreach might help)

Comment: I'm using SELECT CONCAT like Andrey suggested, so I get the rows already formated. The output of $row[0], $row[1], $row[2], is the same tan only $row[0], I mean, if I put only `echo $row[0]` output is /images/álbum_name/photo.jpg, and if I add other echos below, output is the same. In addition, I tryed to echo only $row[1] or $row[2] and there is no output, so only the [0] seems to be filled, the others are empty.
I guess that this happen because the number inside [] indicates the field and not the row.
How can I indicate the row and not the field?

Comment: Output from: 
`while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    print('<p>'.$row[0].'</p>');  
}`
is what I spected, but I only get a list of the paths (/images/álbum_name/photo.jpg, /images/álbum_name/photo1.jpg, etc) and I want to save they in variables.

Comment: Oh, I understand now what you were asking for with the CONCAT, you would get the same approach joining the two strings in PHP.

You can use arrays again for this.`

`$images = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_BOTH)) { $images[] = $row[0] }`

And you get the results indexed in the position $images[0], $images[1], $images[2], etc

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot! now I can handle they by their indexes.. ^^

Comment: You are welcome. This was my first answer, I'm glad you found it useful :)

Answer (score 0):

$sql = "SELECT CONCAT(album_name, '/', img_name) FROM gallery WHERE status = 1 ORDER by date DESC LIMIT 15";

Comment: Excellent, I didn't know the "concat" parameter, that works perfectly to format the results, now don't you know how can I set each row to a variable?

Comment: Like @Dev_NIX write - $gallery = $mysqli->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); you get array with all rows. you also can look at function array_column: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Comment: My mistake use $mysqli->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);